# How do I capture a video without audio with CameraX?

Tags: android-camerax

I'm able to successfully capture a video using a VideoCapture use case in CameraX. However, I do not want to capture audio. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem?!

Comment: Yes. It's currently not possible: https://groups.google.com/a/android.com/g/camerax-developers/c/fsY3j4x_lA0/m/921lFEqyAgAJ